# Placing divs side by side, but not in line

Tags: html, css

Consider the follwoing html code:

```
 <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
 <div id="CPU1"></div>

 <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
 <div id="CPU2"></div>

 <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
 <div id="CPU3"></div>

 <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
 <div id="CPU4"></div>
```

CSS goes like this:

```
 #CPU1{
   width:600px; 
   height:300px; 
   margin-top: 20px;
   float:left;
}
 #CPU2{
   width:600px; 
   height:300px; 
   margin-top: 20px;
   float:right;
}
 #CPU3{
   width:600px; 
   height:300px; 
   margin-top: 20px;
   float:left;
}
 #CPU4{
   width:600px; 
   height:300px; 
   margin-top: 20px;
   float:right;
}
```

I need to place all the four divs side by side, i.e. CPU1 and CPU2, beside each other and in the next line CPU3 and CPU4 (beside each other).

But it is not organised. My CPU1 tag is not inline with CPU2 tag, but when I remove the  `<h3>` tag then all the divs are inline.

How can I have the title on the div tags? 
An image for your reference. [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKYJy.jpg)

I need this but with Title: [Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOMN2.jpg)

Comment: @user3801433 added an image. Plz hav a look.

Comment: Put a picture about the think what you want

Comment: i think this happens due to <h3> tag between them.

Comment: @Kermani Added a pic. Plz hav a look.

Comment: What's wrong with having them inline? That's literally what you describe in a comment below: "I just need to put all the divs in line with the title."

Comment: By inline I meant, see the image 2(Required).

Comment: Put both `<h3>` and `<div>` in another `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the

inside the DIV. Such as:

```
<div id="CPU1">
    <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
    <div class="add_graph_here"></div>
</div>


<div id="CPU2">
    <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
    <div class="add_graph_here"></div>
</div>


<div id="CPU3">
    <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
    <div class="add_graph_here"></div>
</div>


<div id="CPU4">
    <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
    <div class="add_graph_here"></div>
</div>
```

However, if your browsers width is wide enough (+1800px) the boxes will be plaxed incorrectly (according to your expectations). 
For this reason, add in the CSS:

```
#CPU1{
   width:50%; 
   height:300px; 
   margin-top: 20px;
   float:left;
}
 #CPU2{
   width:50%; 
   height:300px; 
   margin-top: 20px;
   float:right;
}
 #CPU3{
   width:50%; 
   height:300px; 
   margin-top: 20px;
   float:left;
}
 #CPU4{
   width:50%; 
   height:300px; 
   margin-top: 20px;
   float:right;
}

 .add_graph_here { /*this represents your graph*/
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     background: #DDD;
     border: 4px solid #ABABAB;
 }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t3xadz9v/)**

Comment: Have tried inserting `<h3>` inside, the title does not appear.

Comment: This works when the div id contains only text. But as soon as it contains graph, the title vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap divs in rows like

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div id="CPU1"></div>
        <div id="CPU2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 
        <div id="CPU3"></div>
        <div id="CPU4"></div>
    </div>
</wrapper>
```

give all CPU divs

```
float: left
```

and for row

```
.row {
    float: left;
}
```

and for wrapper

```
.wrapper {
    with: 1200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use float here. Take a look at this [click me](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

Comment: can't you use an html table for this? i think it will be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your blocks and add "clear: left" to third block

HTML:

```
<div id="CPU1">
    <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="CPU2">
    <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="CPU3">
    <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="CPU4">
    <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#CPU1{
    width:600px; 
    height:300px; 
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
}
#CPU2{
    width:600px; 
    height:300px; 
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
}
#CPU3{
    width:600px; 
    height:300px; 
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
#CPU4{
    width:600px; 
    height:300px; 
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

then add your content to empty div's

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="CPU1" style=" height:400px;">
<h3>CPU Plot </h3>
 <div id="CPU1"  style="border:1px solid;"></div>
</div>
 <div id="CPU2" style=" height:400px;">
<h3>CPU Plot </h3>
<div id="CPU2"  style="border:1px solid;"></div></div>
<div id="CPU3" style=" height:400px;">
<h3>CPU Plot </h3>
<div id="CPU3"  style="border:1px solid;"></div>
</div>
<div id="CPU4" style=" height:400px;">
 <h3>CPU Plot </h3>
<div id="CPU4" style="border:1px solid;"></div>
</div>
```

just for example style according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="CPU1">
<h3>CPU Plot </h3>
cpu1
</div>

<div id="CPU2">
<h3>CPU Plot </h3>
cpu2
</div></div>

<div class="row">
<div id="CPU3">
<h3>CPU Plot </h3>
cpu3
</div>

<div id="CPU4">
<h3>CPU Plot </h3>
cpu4
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#CPU1{
width:100px; 
height:100px; 
float:left;
display: inline-block;
}

#CPU2{
width:100px; 
height:100px; 
float:right;
display: inline-block;
}

#CPU3{
width:100px; 
height:100px; 
float:left;
display: inline-block;
}

#CPU4{
width:100px; 
height:100px; 
float:right;
display: inline-block;

}

.row{
width:300px;
clear:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/htevn7Ln/2/

You can also remove container rows and add "clear:left" to #CPU3.

Comment: This works when the div id contains only text. But as soon as it contains graph. It was again as first image.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand. What do yo mean by "the div id contains only text" ?